# Trying to get property of non-object using codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
[error page image][1]
```

Trying to get property of non-object using codeigniter like that error message displaying in view page when the no records founds in database table please resolve my problem(when no records founds in database form should be displayed in view page)

**controller**

```
 public function buyerdetails_form() {
            $this->load->helper('url');

             $result = $this->Profile_model->buyer_details();
            $data['c_address']=$result->address;
            $data['c_pincode']=$result->pincode;
            $data['c_district']=$result->district;
            $data['c_city']=$result->city;
            $data['c_state']=$result->state;
            $data['c_country']=$result->country;
            $this->load->view('buyerdetails_form',$data);

    }
```

**model**

```
public function buyer_details()
{
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('customer_otherdetails');
    $this->db->where('customerid_fk', $this->session->id);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    $rows = $query->result(); //so you only have to call result once
    if($query->num_rows() > 0)
    {
        foreach($rows as $row)
        {
            //add all data to session
            $newdataa = array(
              'address' => $row->address,
              'pincode' => $row->pincode,
              'city' => $row->city,
              'district' => $row->district,
              'state' => $row->state,
              'country' => $row->country,
            );
        }
        $this->session->set_userdata($newdataa);
        //put the return outside the if
        //return $query->result();
    }
   // return $rows; //this will be an empty array if no data found
     return $query->row();

}
```

**view**

```
<li class="has-sub" >
                            <span>Country</span>
                            <span><?php echo  $c_country; ?></span>
                            <a onclick="hideHasSub()" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseone">
                                <span class="profile-edit" onclick="" >Edit</span></span>
                            </a>
                            <div style="clear:both;"></div>
                        </li>
                        <div  class="sub">
                            <div class="panel-body ">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2 text-center">

                                             <label style="display:inline;">Country</label> 
                                             <input type="text" name="id" value="<?php echo  $this->session->id; ?>" />
                                             <input style="width:50%;height:20px;" type ="text" class="form-control" name="country" value="<?php echo  $c_country; ?>"/></br>
                                             <p style="font-size: 12px;"><b>Note:</b> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.</p>
                                             <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-success" style="width:70px;">
<!--                                            <button type="button"  style="margin:0 10px;">Save</button>-->

                                        <button  type="button" class="btn btn-warning cancel-name " >Cancel</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

Comment: you will need to use `isset()` to check for null or empty variables

Comment: You should use is_array($yourvar) function before print your variable, if there will be value then it will show either you can show 'Records not found' in else statement.

Comment: @ImmortalDude thank you your code is working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change this in your model 
`$rows = $query->result_array();`

and also use `if(isset){}` to check for empty